# Flask: spawning a single async sub-task within a request

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous

I have seen a few variants of my question but not quite exactly what I am looking for, hence opening a new question.

I have a Flask/Gunicorn app that for each request inserts some data in a store and, consequently, kicks off an indexing job. The indexing is 2-4 times longer than the main data write and I would like to do that asynchronously to reduce the response latency.

The overall request lifespan is 100-150ms for a large request body.

I have thought about a few ways to do this, that is as resource-efficient as possible:

- Use Celery. This seems the most obvious way to do it, but I don't want to introduce a large library and most of all, a dependency on Redis or other system packages.
- Use `subprocess.Popen`. This may be a good route but my bottleneck is I/O, so threads could be more efficient.
- Using threads? I am not sure how and if that can be done. All I know is how to launch multiple processes concurrently with `ThreadPoolExecutor`, but I only need to spawn one additional task, and return immediately without waiting for the results.
- `asyncio`? This too I am not sure how to apply to my situation. `asyncio` has always a blocking call.
- Launching data write and indexing concurrently: not doable. I have to wait for a response from the data write to launch indexing.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually should have perused the Python manual section on concurrency better: the `threading` module does just what I needed: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/threading.html

And I confirmed with some dummy sleep code that the sub-thread gets completed even after the Flask request is completed.

Answer (score 0):

Celery will be your best bet - it's exactly what it's for.

If you have a need to introduce dependencies, it's not a bad thing to have dependencies.  Just as long as you don't have unneeded dependencies.

Depending on your architecture, though, more advanced and locked-in solutions might be available.  You could, if you're using AWS, launch an AWS Lambda function by firing off an AWS SNS notification, and have that handle what it needs to do.  The sky is the limit.

Comment: Thank for the suggestion Adam, probably in 99% of the cases I would have done so. However this is an open-source project and I want to keep depedencies to a minimum.

Comment: Even in open-source, dependencies are not a bad thing.  [Flask itself](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/8c2c802f19cf220d6e177414d315dcc6be6ac759/setup.py#L71) for instance, has some.

Comment: Dependencies on Python libraries are easily managed. Dependencies on an external package such as Redis put an additional burden on the adopter.

Comment: The same requirement must then be passed on to the user.  They want to use something that has a long running task, the correct way to do this is with Celery, therefore they're going to have to install redis, rabbitmq, what have you.  If you're distributing this, then consider a makefile which installs redis or similar, to make it easier.